# How to stop wget command?

Tags: command-line, wget, mirrors

I accidentally mirrored a whole website using wget. Whenever I try to delete the downloaded file, it keeps reappearing & trying to download again. How do I stop this?

Comment: Kill the running `wget` command.

Comment: If this is running in Terminal, just Press Ctrl+C.

Answer (score 2):

Kill the `wget` command by using `pkill`, and sending the TERM signal (default for the command):

```
pkill -x wget
```

If this doesn't work, send the KILL signal instead:

```
pkill -9 -x wget
```